# Adding multiple time values from excel cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I am trying to add multiple time values in hh:mm:ss say,

```
F16 - 00:15:00
F17 - 00:18:00
F18 - 00:20:00
```

should provide result in F19 as 00.53.00 but its not adding up any value and instead showing 00:00:00.
Please suggest which cell format should I choose for sum cell.

Additional note - I try the hh:mm format for my duration cells, F16, F17, F18 but as soon I entered the time - 00:10 it translated to 02:24.

Thanks.

Comment: are you entering `00.10` or `00:10`?  `02:24:00` equates to `0.1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following User Defined Function:

```
Public Function tsum(rng As Range) As String
    Dim t As Date, cell As Range
    For Each cell In rng
        t = t + TimeValue(cell.Text)
    Next cell
    tsum = Format(t, "hh:mm:ss")
End Function
```

[image]

**NOTE:**

To get a genuine Excel date/time, just wrap the function like:

```
=TIMEVALUE(tsum(E16:E18))
```

and format anyway you like.

Answer (score 0):

**:Caveat:**

*Below show method are based on the sample data shared by OP.*

---

- The TIME value you are using in `F16:F18`, doesn't needs any special method or formula because, you can get expected result by using simple `SUM function`.

*I'm showing you four possibilities.*

---

**Possibility 1:**

[image]

- Cell format applied is TIME.
- Since Time starts with `00` therefore Excel converts them as `12`.
- Formula used is: `=SUM(O18:O20)`

---

**Possibility 2:**

[image]

- Cell format applied is CUSTOM `HH:MM:SS`.
- Formula used is: `=SUM(P18:P20)`

---

**Possibility 3:**

[image]

- TIME entered as DECIMAL Value.
- Cell format applied is GENERAL.
- Formula used is: `=tSUM(Q18:Q20)`, UDF suggested by @Gary's Student.

---

**Possibility 4:**

[image]

- TIME entered as DECIMAL Value.
- Cell format applied is GENERAL.
- Formula used is an Array (CSE), need to finish with **Ctrl+shift+Enter**:

`{=TEXT(SUM(RIGHT(Q18:Q20,5)+0),"00.00")}`

---

**N.B.**

- You may use any of the methods, best suitable are `Possibility 1 and 2`, suits data entered in `F16:F18`.
- Adjust cell references in the formula as needed,